# BigQuery Array Element Multiplicaton

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Noob question here:

I have a BQ table with a nested structure containing 2 arrays, x and y.  I want to create either a new array of x*y  or have the 2 arrays unnested and create a flattened table of x, y & x*y values.

```
WITH
  tests AS (
  SELECT
  [  struct("test1" AS test,
        [0.1576,0.9706,0.9572,0.4854,0.8003,0.1419,0.4218,0.9157,0.7922,0.9595] AS x,
        [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20] AS y),
    struct("test2" AS test,
        [0.8147,0.9058,0.1270,0.9134,0.6324,0.0975,0.2785,0.5469,0.9575, 0.9649] AS x,
        [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20] AS y),
   struct("test3" AS test,
        [0.6557,0.0357,0.8491,0.9340,0.6787,0.7577,0.7431,0.3922,0.6555,0.1712] AS x,
        [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20] AS y)
   ] AS measurements)


SELECT
  test, x,y
FROM
  tests t, unnest(t.measurements)
```

I would like extend the above query to get a flattened table with test number, x, y and x*y like this, or something similar:

| tests | x | y | x*y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test1 | 0.1576 | 11 | 1.7366 |
| test1 | 0.9706 | 12 | 11.6472 |
| test1 | 0.9572 | 13 | 12.4436 |
| test1 | 0.4854 | 14 | 6.7956 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| test3 | 0.1712 | 20 | 3.4240 |

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select test, x, y, round(x*y, 4) as x_multiply_y
from tests, unnest(measurements),
unnest(x) x with offset 
join unnest(y) y with offset 
using(offset)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, that works for the example.  If I extend it to give x*y*z data by adding on another cross join to an additional column it also works but when the array lengths of x, y & z get very big (10000+ elements) BQ struggles and complains of slots and large amounts of shuffled data.  Any thoughts on alternatives or methods to just extraxt the x,y & z arrays and add them as new columns to the table?

Comment: yo can try to materialize intermediate steps. for example first - `from tests, unnest(measurements)` into table1, then `unnest(x) x with offset ` and `unnest(y) y with offset ` into respectively table2 and table 3 and finally joint those last two tables ...